# Add custom php functions file to all Bolt CMS extensions

Tags: php, symfony, bolt-cms

There's a list of functions I'd like to have available to all of my local extensions. Is there a seamless way to include a "functions.php" file so that all of my extensions have the PHP functions available to use?

Answer (score 0):

Define a "master" extension, make your other extensions "require" that master, and expand on the "autoload" section, something like this example:

`"autoload" : {
        "files" : [
            "init.php"
        ],
        "psr-4" : {
            "Bolt\\Extension\\Gawain\\Cord\\" : [
                "",
                "src/"
            ],
            "Book\\Library\\" : "lib/"
        },
        "classmap" : [
            "vendor/NameLess/"
        ]
    },`

See the [Composer autoload docs](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#autoload) for more info.

Comment: Trying to better understand Composer -- in this example, is "Book\\Library\\" : "lib/" the directory you'd put the functions?

Comment: In the case you point to, in the `lib/` directory would be class files that have the `namespace Book\Library;`.

Comment: Looking at your OP, you're probably aiming for the classmap, and yes from memory, `"vendor/NameLess/"` is a directory.